# How to calculate dimensions of a pyramid consisting of spheres?

Tags: spheres

[I have found an image](https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0496/0085/products/Ball-Pyramid-Puzzle-WG-451.jpg?v=1426220331) that shows my problem pretty well. At the top, you can see a single phere stacked ontop of three other ones. Let's say the radius of all the spheres is a. I would like to calculate the height of a pyramid consisting of 4 such spheres, but I am completely lost how to do it. I tried applying pythagoras theorem on the spheres, but I can't find any way that works.

[image]

Comment: you may want to read about the cannonball problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannonball_problem

Comment: @CodeSharpMarvin Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

**Four** spheres are arranged in such way that their centers form a [tetrahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron).

[image]